# Cross dependencies issue: object references an unsaved transient instance save the transient instance before flushing

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Seems that issue is being asked over and over still I do not find an answer to solve mine. I have a domain model below. I'm required for every newly create or update Sec User make sure it has a profile, if not then create a new one and assign to it.

The same required for profile - every time during save to check whether it has a workspace, if not then create one. This is done to make sure all Sec User-s have at least one workspace. Besides owner himself a workspace may have different contributors.

When I'm trying to save Sec User, I always get:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance save the transient instance before flushing
```

In general I do understand the nature of issue. Instance passed in constructor is not persisted thus doesn't have an id. Still I don't know how to force this 3 inserts be a part of a single transaction and handle references correctly.

```
class SecUser implements Serializable {

    String email

    static hasOne = [profile: Profile]

    def beforeValidate() {
        if (profile == null) {
            profile = new Profile(secUser: this)
        }
        profile.validate()
    }

}

class Profile {

    static belongsTo = [secUser: SecUser]

    static hasMany = [workspaces: Workspace]

    static constraints = {
        workspaces minSize: 1
    }

    def beforeValidate() {
        if (workspaces == null || workspaces.isEmpty()) {
            def workspace = new Workspace(owner: this).save()
            workspaces = [workspace]
        }
    }
}

class Workspace {

    String title = "Workspace ${10000 + new Random().nextInt(89999)}"

    static hasOne = [owner: Profile]

    static belongsTo = Profile

    static hasMany = [contributors: Profile]

}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I have replaced

```
workspaces = [workspace]
```

to

```
this.addToWorkspaces(workspace)
```

now I get this:

> ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Referential integrity constraint
>   violation: "FK_MYFCABJIQ83AG2CLBDF61MPA5: PUBLIC.PROFILE_WORKSPACES
>   FOREIGN KEY(WORKSPACE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKSPACE(ID) (0)"; SQL
>   statement: insert into profile_workspaces (profile_id, owner_id)
>   values (?, ?) [23506-176].

A new join table has been generated which has 3 columns. I see it tries to make a wrong insert. it should be insert to owner_id, workspace_id (profile_id should be empty)

Comment: You should call `this.addToWorkspaces(workspace)` instead of `workspaces = [workspace]`. You should also save the profile once validated.

Comment: Ok now I get this: ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_MYFCABJIQ83AG2CLBDF61MPA5: PUBLIC.PROFILE_WORKSPACES FOREIGN KEY(WORKSPACE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.WORKSPACE(ID) (0)"; SQL statement:
insert into profile_workspaces (profile_id, owner_id) values (?, ?) [23506-176]. a new join table has been generated which has 3 columns. I see it tries to make a wrong insert. it should be insert to owner_id, workspace_id @defectus

Comment: You've got two associations between Profile and Workspace: a many-to-many and a one-to-one. The many-to-many should result in a join table, which in your case looks like is named profile_workspaces. profile_workspaces should have only two columns: profile_id and workspace_id. I think your one-to-one between Profile and Workspace is not working. You should have a hasOne() on the owning-side (ex. Profile) and either a property (ex. owner) or a belongsTo() on the owned/dependent side (ex. Workspace). Just like the one-to-one between SecUser and Profile.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm dealing with a business transaction that involves multiple domain objects, I create a Grails service. Using a service would simplify domain unit testing and it also helps to describe what your code is trying to accomplish. Think of it as the Transaction Script design pattern (Gang of Four).

Your service can have create() and update() methods, and then you would call those from your controllers. Then, your service would wire up the SecUser, Profile, and Workspace as you need fit.

Comment: so you have a service. still entire domain has cross references. you can't simply save stuff without relations. this has nothing to do with GoF and design patterns. @Emmanuel